# Returning Double Escaped JSON text in PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql, escaping, double

**Need help**

I have a PostgreSQL Function, which will update a JSON Column having data like "{"abcd:"xyz"}"
with a similar format and return the output.

I am using CTE Query with Returning clause. Only problem is its giving output as Double Escaped i.e "{\""abcd:\""xyz""}".

And if I am using (columnName #>> '{}' )::json, its giving me back "{""abcd:""xyz""}".

How do I get correct output from the function.

Select Query on the table gives as it is , but output from function gives Double-Escaped. How do I solve it.

Any suggestion please.

Comment: Will need to see the function code in order to help solving this. Also the actual data as {"abcd:"xyz"} is invalid JSON.

Comment: Ok, give me some time. I will post a sample code. I understand, some typing mistakes I have done while posting the question.